# Issue Storing File Paths in Javascript Array from C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to store all of file paths from a string array in C# into a Javascript array and it works and stores them all in the array but the path's slashes are removed so the file path doesn't read as normal and produces an error. The file path is shown in the following and as you can see in the end of the path everything collides together because the slashes disappear.: [image]

If the slashes were in there then the file path should be able to be read in my code sample I will include which I have tested with file paths. I was just wondering how to, in my code, have the slashes retained in javascript.

*What my code does is pass in an array of strings seperated by a semicolon from c# razor code in MVC and then puts each one in an array in Javascript and this is where it strips the slashes. Then the image is displayed using URL.Content and the file path.*

ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED!

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    @model Tuple
    <string, string[]>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
         scale=1.0">
        <title>My ASP.NET Application</title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:800px;height:400px;border:3px solid #000;margin:0 
     auto;margin-top:70px;position:relative;">
        <img src="" style="width:100%;height:100%;" id="img" />
        <p style="position:absolute;top:45%;font- 
     size:22px;color:#fff;left:10px;cursor:pointer;" id="left">
            < </p>
                <p style="position:absolute;top:45%;font- 
    size:22px;color:#fff;right:10px;cursor:pointer;" id="right">></p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = [];
    var first = "@Model.Item1";
    counter = 0;

    @foreach(string i in Model.Item2) {

        <
        text > arr.push("@i") < /text>
    }

    $('#right').click(function() {
        if (counter == 0) {

        } else {
            counter--;
        }
    });

    $('#left').click(function() {
        if (counter == 0) {

        } else {
            counter--;
        }
    });

    var image = document.getElementById("img");
    image.src = "@Url.Content("~/Practice/Images / ")" + arr[0];
</script>
```

Comment: The img.src line of code at the bottom produces location so it doesn't necessarily throw an error in the compiler but in the browser it says "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found". The problem is with the slashes disappearing though because I plugged in the hardcoded location and it showed the image with Url.Content.

Comment: Please show us the HTML that is generated using the browser's `View Source`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is problem with the way you populate the arr object. Somehow javascript escape sequence removes the slashes. Remove this @foreach(string i in Model.Item2) loop and You can directly assign value to arr as below.

```
var arr = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Item2));
```